# Confusion about gravitational field strength and gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration

Do all objects on earth experience the same gravitational field strength and if so why does weight, which is defined as the amount of gravity acting on an object, change? I think I am confusing gravitational force and gravitational strength to be the same. Please help

Comment: FWIW, [little $g$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth) depends slightly on the position on Earth's surface.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the gravitational field strength at a point near the surface of the earth as the force of gravity per unit mass. Near the surface of the earth the gravitational force is $mg$. That makes the gravitational strength $\frac{mg}{m}=g$, which is the same for all masses near the surface of the earth.

Hope this helps.